Hierarchical Slicer in Power BI
I am trying to create a slicer in Power BI that can allow me to filter based on a hierarchy. The basics of the hierarchy are as in a table like this:



NodeID
NodeName
ParentNodeID




1
Company 1
{NULL}


2
Region 1
1


3
Team 1
2


4
Team 2
2


5
Region 2
1


6
Team 3
5


7
Team 4
5



Then, I have records in data tables similar to below that I need to filter based on the hierarchy:



RecordID
CustomerName
NodeID




1
Smith, John
4


2
Jones, Larry
6


3
Clark, Susan
6



And, I would like to have a slicer that looks something like this:

Client  1

Region 1

Team 1

Team 2



Region 2

Team 3

Team 4






Such that, if the user selects Team 2, they would only see records in the visuals that were in Team 2. And, if they selected Region 1, they would see records in Team 1 or Team 2.
The selection would need to be multi-selectable, and I would also need to be able to restrict selections available based on the user.
For example:

User A might only have access to Region 2, so shouldn’t be able to select any nodes outside of that region.

User B might only have access to Teams 2 and 4, so shouldn’t be able to select anything else.


Can anyone help me with this? The hierarchy slicer information that I’ve looked through, so far, hasn’t been very helpful, as it’s based on static groupings. I need something based on parent/child relationships at unknown levels (meaning that the data rows could be associated at ANY level in the hierarchy, not just at the Team level or Region level, etc.)
I have looked at the Hierarchy Slicer, but couldn't figure out a way to make that work with our existing hierarchy setup.

I use deep self-relating tables and for the purpose of clarity in power bi, I usually create a separate table in power query that references the hierarchy table. I call this table parent_node. I don't filter or change anything to the query. I then create a relationship in power bi (I try to maintain single cross-filter direction) and then I can use the node name of this table in filters and slicers without having to use complex relational DAX equations.
I just experimented with this using some of my self-joined data as well as the sample dataset as seen in the image below.

